# Adding internal links (TOC) to long .py script?

Tags: python-3.x, anchor

I am working on a 3D Slicer module and it's getting quite long. I was wondering if there is a way to add a table of contents at the top that provides internal links to parts of the .py script.

I have read through the Sphinx docs and haven't found any other similar packages.

Comment: It's time to split it to smaller scripts. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Please show us some code. What you have tried and any errors you receive.